Как сравнить списки по количеству элементов в них?
Дан список чисел a.  Напишите программу, которая вернет True, если в списке больше нечетных чисел, и False — во всех остальных случаях. Результат сохраните в result.
Внизу мой код, но выдает неправильное логическое выражение. Кол-во элементов выдает правильно, но при сравнении выходит неверный ответ. Хотя логически все должно быть правильно. В чем моя ошибка?
Дано: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]  выдает все время True
i = 0
even_numbers = []
odd_numbers = []


for i in a:
    if i % 2 == 0:
       even_numbers.append(i)
    else:
       odd_numbers.append(i)
       if len(odd_numbers) > len(even_numbers):
          result = True
        else:
           result = False


@StanislavVolodarskiy это просто чума

print(sum(map(lambda i: 2 * (i % 2) - 1, a)) > 0).

Просто команда сравнения попала в цикл, а в нём в else
i = 0
even_numbers = []
odd_numbers = []


for i in a:
    if i % 2 == 0:
       even_numbers.append(i)
    else:
       odd_numbers.append(i)
if len(odd_numbers) > len(even_numbers):
   result = True
else:
   result = False


Вообще, там дополнительные списки не нужны, нужно просто считать нечётные. Если их больше половины, тогда истина.
odd_numbers = 0
for i in a:
    if i % 2 > 0:
       odd_numbers += 1
result = odd_numbers > len(a) / 2

А по-модному можно сделать так:
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(list(map(lambda i : i % 2 > 0, a)).count(True) > len(a) / 2)


И, наконец, перл, вершина искусства! От Станислава:
print(sum(map(lambda i: 2 * (i % 2) - 1, a)) > 0)

Просто хочется объяснить, что там проиходит:

"2 * (i % 2) - 1" возвращает 1 для нечётных и -1 для чётных.
map сопоставляет исходному массиву массив (1).
sum это всё суммирует, суммирует...
И если положительных единичек больше, чем отрицательных, то сумма больше нуля!

Вау!

odd_numbers > len(a) / 2 -> 2 * odd_numbers > len(a). Лучше считать без вещественных чисел.

Самый модный способ: print(2 * sum(map(lambda i: i % 2, a)) > len(a)).

О, питонный остаток от деления)))

tio.run
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(sum(x & 1 for x in a) > len(a) >> 1)


Коротко, чётко, тривиально.

Кому интересно: померил время исполнения решения Qwertiy с битовыми операциями против времени моего решения с остатком. Битовый вариант на моем железе 2 * 10^-6, мой вариант с остатком 5 * 10^-6. Так-то, в 2.5 раза быстрее. Красиво, чо уж…

@AlexeyTrukhanov, у меня ещё из других языков привычка нечётность проверять через &1 потому что %2 может выдать -1. Но питон так не делает)

@Qwertiy любопытно про -1 в качестве остатка. А это баг или фича? В каких случаях остаток получается -1?

@AlexeyTrukhanov, честно говоря, я не совсем уверен. Вроде бы в разных языках есть разные варианты. Сейчас проверил значения 1%2, -1%2, 1%-2, -1%-2. На си++, js, vb.net и php получилось 1 -1 1 -1 - знак как у числителя. На питоне 1 1 -1 -1 - знак как у знаменателя. PS: Ну знак - это для двойки, а там по сути полноценные отрицательные остатки. Надо было 2/3 проверять.

@Qwertiy спасибо за подробный разбор! Интересно.

Чисто из любви к искусству. Суммируем количество нечетных и делим на длину исходного списка, сравниваем результат с 0.5. Если больше - в результате истина, если меньше или равно - ложь.
result = sum(i % 2 != 0 for i in a) / len(a) > 0.5

UPD
Согласно комментарию Stanislav Volodarsky вынужден избавится от вещественных чисел.
result = 2 * sum(i % 2 != 0 for i in a) > len(a) 

UPD 2
В результате избавился от списка (спасибо Qwertiy) и неравенства с нулем (спасибо CrazyElf). Вот так красиво:
result = 2 * sum(i % 2 for i in a) > len(a) 


Круто, но нужно докрутить с учётом первого замечания Станислава.

@rotabor невозможно спорить.  Добавил.

Списки не нужны...

@Qwertiy спасибо, исправил

!= 0 тоже не нужно )  Правда, это уже есть в комментариях к другому ответу...

@CrazyElf блин, точно! Спасибо.
